# qt Window make no modal (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, modal-dialog

There are two windows in my qt app, it's main and settings window. When i create Settings Window, i can't use main window, because my new window is modal, and i need to use two windows.
How do i make my window no modal?

---

I use this code:

```
String inputDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"), 
"/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

---

I press on my bar and show my Setting window

```
//Input dir
void SecondWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

    inputDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"), "/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);


    qDebug() << inputDir;

    ui->lineEdit_3->setText(inputDir);
}
```

I create this form to get directory which i choosen. And as result of this code: i create a modal settings window.

---

I see show(), but i don't understand how can i use show() in my situation.

How can i make my new Settings Window as modal window?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I add some information, what do you think?

Comment: Is the file (dir.) dialog that 2nd window you want to have non-modal? If so, you're mission is lost. [QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory): _This is a convenience **static** function that will return an existing directory selected by the user._ ... _This function creates a **modal** file dialog_ Specifically on Windows, this is a wrapper to use the native dialog of the Windows API. For a non-modal file dialog, you have to instance `QFileDialog`. (But, it's not a native dialog anymore in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

Your second window should inherit QWidget (:public QWidget) and you can use its show() method to show it

```
QWidget* w = new QWidget();
w->show();
```